# Let $f_{n}(x) = \frac{\arctan(nx)}{\sqrt{n}}$ show that it converges uniformly to $f$ - Proof Verification

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, proof-writing, uniform-convergence

Let $f_{n}(x) = \frac{\arctan(nx)}{\sqrt{n}}$, show that it converges uniformly to $f$ .

Examining the function, we see that $f_{n} \rightarrow 0$ as we take $n \rightarrow \infty$

So it becomes having to show:

$$\|f_{n}(x) - f(x) \|_{\infty} \rightarrow 0$$

Therefore:

$$\|f_{n}(x) - f(x) \|_{\infty} = \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}}\Bigg|\frac{\arctan(nx)}{\sqrt{n}}\Bigg| < \frac{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\sqrt{n}} \\ \Rightarrow \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\sqrt{n}} \rightarrow 0 $$

So this is the scratch work. Now how do I formally state to take a specific $n > N$ ? I'm trying to tie together my ability to write out this process in a good mathematical manner.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let $\epsilon > 0$. Let $n \geq 4\epsilon^{-2}$, then $\|f_n\|_{\infty} \leq \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{n}} \leq \frac{\pi\epsilon}{4} < \epsilon$.

Comment: Thanks for the help